# UWP bind to dependency property

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created a UWP project using the Template studio, and I am trying to implement a custom control.

This is what it looks like:

.xaml.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MyButton : UserControl
    {
        public MyButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ImageSource Icon
        {
            get => (ImageSource)GetValue(s_iconProperty);
            set => SetValue(s_iconProperty, value);
        }

        public ImageSource Pointer
        {
            get => (ImageSource)GetValue(s_pointerProperty);
            set => SetValue(s_pointerProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty s_iconProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyButton), null);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty s_pointerProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Pointer", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyButton), null);
    }
```

.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="...Main.Components.MyButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:...Main.Components"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" Width="755.357">
    <Button Margin="0,1,1,-1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-375,-152,-375,-148" Width="750" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="39,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="{?!?!?!}"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,126,0,0" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="403"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="602,121,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Basically, it has two images inside a grid, which I would like to bind to my dependecy properties, `Icon` and `Pointer`.

In the designer of my control I can't see the dependency properties, but I can see them in the designer of  page on which I have the custom button.

I have followed this tutorial, and tried to do the same: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32795.uwp-creating-user-control.aspx, but when I click on my first image --> Source in the custom control's designer, the "create data binding" option is not even available - it is disabled.

I have tried to set the data binding like this:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="39,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
```

but I realize that this is probably not the right syntax.

How do I bind to these dependency properties, is there a simple way?

I have created the control by using Add new item... User Control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have tried to set the data binding like this:
>   `<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="39,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>`

This way you set the data binding in the XAML of the user control is correct. But you didn't set the [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_DataContext) for the binding. Without the data source the binding will not work. Just set the `Datacontext` inside your user control it will work. Code as follows:

```
public MyButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
}

public ImageSource Icon
{
    get => (ImageSource)GetValue(s_iconProperty);
    set => SetValue(s_iconProperty, value);
}
```

Then you can use the user control to set the image source, for example:

```
<local:MyButton
    Width="600"
    Height="800"
    Icon="Assets/A.jpg" />
```

More details about binding inside user control you could reference [this article](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html).